# Identify unknown LEGO set bag 2, clear tubes with blue center and blue minifig with clear helmet?

Tags: set-identification

Everything is grey and blue, there is a robot/alien type guy with a clear helmet, there are 2 oversized light blue hands and some long rubber, flexible things leading us to believe he's controlling a robot. Possibly from a Marvel or Star Wars set. Lots of small clear blue pieces.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This is part of  [70901-1: Mr. Freeze Ice Attack](https://brickset.com/sets/70901-1/Mr-Freeze-Ice-Attack)

[image]